# Adding comment feature in Django DetailView?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

What the simplest logic i can add in `class HotelDetailView(DetailView)` so users can comment on a particular hotel detail page. And it capture user too.

**models.py**

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
    name     = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    owner    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    image    = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True)


class CommentOnHotel(models.Model):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    published = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.hotel.name, self.user.email)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class CommentOnHotelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CommentOnHotel
        fields = ['content']
```

**views.py**

```
class HotelDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Hotel
    ........
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I gave you the better approach for that, but if you want to make all logic and functions at **DetailView** which is not recommended, here is the solution; you need to override **POST** function of **DetaiView**:

```
class HotelDetailView(DetailView):
     model = Hotel

     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         # get the hotel object
         hotel = self.get_object()
         #check for validation of form
         form = CommentOnHotelForm({
            "hotel": hotel,
            "user" :request.user
            "comment": request.POST.comment
         })

         if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            #choose where you want to redirect
```

Comment: Its totally different i don't wanna do like this. I wanna implement like this https://youtu.be/An4hW4TjKhE but its implemented in function based view same thing i wanna do in class based view.

Comment: If possible can u provide that one too which u told 1st. And why thats better approach then this.

Comment: can u provide that code too & please tell why that is better solution.